# Linear Discriminant Analysis Predictions Change Based on Scaling of New Data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, pca, discriminant-analysis

My data high dimensional (80,000 features) and only 5 different classes. The values for the features are not raw counts but are rather percents (decimals actually) such that the sum of the 80,000 features for any observation is 1.

When I was running LDA it was error-ing out because all the values are between 10e-3 and 10e-5. I scaled everything by multiplying by 10,000 and LDA compiled.

When I am testing my new data (same structure) using the predict function, I am heavily favoring one class. Then I scaled my new data by 10,000 (like i did before) the predictions are mostly correct. When I scaled my data by 30,000 and the predictions are 100% correct.

My question is why is this happening and how should I construct the LDA and transform the new data to get accurate predictions on my proportion data.